# Size of element is not changing in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a gauge into a wordpress site.
The gauge is a js object, which show a scrolling bar.

When I set style values of the element locally, the size of the guage changes.

```
            <div id="gauge2" class="gauge-container two" style="display:inline-block; min-height:100px;min-width:100px;float: left;width: 100%; height: 100%;padding-left: 300px;overflow: hidden"></div>
```

When I set it in wordpress site, the size of the element stays the same(very small)

The full code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
  /* ------------------- Default Style ------------------------- */

  .gauge-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    /* float: left; */
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }


  /* ------------------- Alternate Style ------------------------- */

  .gauge-container.two {
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .gauge-container.two > .gauge > .dial {
    stroke: #334455;
    stroke-width: auto;
  }
  .gauge-container.two > .gauge > .value {
    /*stroke: orange;*/
    stroke-dasharray: none;
    stroke-width: 13;
  }
  .gauge-container.two > .gauge > .value {
    /*fill: orange;*/
  }


         .info {
         padding: 20px;
         }


         }
      </style>
             <script>
  /* global window, define, module */
(function(global, factory) {
  var Gauge = factory(global);
  if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD support
    define(function() {return Gauge;});
  }else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    // CommonJS support
    module.exports = Gauge;
  }else {
    // We are probably running in the browser
    global.Gauge = Gauge;
  }
})(typeof window === "undefined" ? this : window, function(global, undefined) {

  var document = global.document,
    slice = Array.prototype.slice,
    requestAnimationFrame = (global.requestAnimationFrame ||
        global.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        global.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        global.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(cb) {
          return setTimeout(cb, 1000 / 60);
        });

  // EXPERIMENTAL!!
  /**
   * Simplistic animation function for animating the gauge. That's all!
   * Options are:
   * {
   *  duration: 1,    // In seconds
   *  start: 0,       // The start value
   *  end: 100,       // The end value
   *  step: function, // REQUIRED! The step function that will be passed the value and does something
   *  easing: function // The easing function. Default is easeInOutCubic
   * }
   */
  function Animation(options) {
    var duration = options.duration,
        currentIteration = 1,
        iterations = 60 * duration,
        start = options.start || 0,
        end = options.end,
        change = end - start,
        step = options.step,
        easing = options.easing || function easeInOutCubic(pos) {
          // https://github.com/danro/easing-js/blob/master/easing.js
          if ((pos/=0.5) < 1) return 0.5*Math.pow(pos,3);
          return 0.5 * (Math.pow((pos-2),3) + 2);
        };

    function animate() {
      var progress = currentIteration / iterations,
          value = change * easing(progress) + start;
      // console.log(progress + ", " + value);
      step(value, currentIteration);
      currentIteration += 1;

      if(progress < 1) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    }
    // start!
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }



  var Gauge = (function() {
    var SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

    var GaugeDefaults = {
      centerX: 50,
      centerY: 50
    };

    var defaultOptions = {
      dialRadius: 40,
      dialStartAngle: 135,
      dialEndAngle: 45,
      value: 0,
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      valueDialClass: "value",
      valueClass: "value-text",
      dialClass: "dial",
      gaugeClass: "gauge",
      showValue: true,
      gaugeColor: null,
      label: function(val) {return Math.round(val);}
    };

    function shallowCopy(/* source, ...targets*/) {
      var target = arguments[0], sources = slice.call(arguments, 1);
      sources.forEach(function(s) {
        for(var k in s) {
          if(s.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            target[k] = s[k];
          }
        }
      });
      return target;
    }

    /**
     * A utility function to create SVG dom tree
     * @param {String} name The SVG element name
     * @param {Object} attrs The attributes as they appear in DOM e.g. stroke-width and not strokeWidth
     * @param {Array} children An array of children (can be created by this same function)
     * @return The SVG element
     */
    function svg(name, attrs, children) {
      var elem = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, name);
      for(var attrName in attrs) {
        elem.setAttribute(attrName, attrs[attrName]);
      }

      if(children) {
        children.forEach(function(c) {
          elem.appendChild(c);
        });
      }
      return elem;
    }

    /**
     * Translates percentage value to angle. e.g. If gauge span angle is 180deg, then 50%
     * will be 90deg
     */
    function getAngle(percentage, gaugeSpanAngle) {
      return percentage * gaugeSpanAngle / 100;
    }

    function normalize(value, min, limit) {
      var val = Number(value);
      if(val > limit) return limit;
      if(val < min) return min;
      return val;
    }

    function getValueInPercentage(value, min, max) {
      var newMax = max - min, newVal = value - min;
      return 100 * newVal / newMax;
      // var absMin = Math.abs(min);
      // return 100 * (absMin + value) / (max + absMin);
    }

    /**
     * Gets cartesian co-ordinates for a specified radius and angle (in degrees)
     * @param cx {Number} The center x co-oriinate
     * @param cy {Number} The center y co-ordinate
     * @param radius {Number} The radius of the circle
     * @param angle {Number} The angle in degrees
     * @return An object with x,y co-ordinates
     */
    function getCartesian(cx, cy, radius, angle) {
      var rad = angle * Math.PI / 180;
      return {
        x: Math.round((cx + radius * Math.cos(rad)) * 1000) / 1000,
        y: Math.round((cy + radius * Math.sin(rad)) * 1000) / 1000
      };
    }

    // Returns start and end points for dial
    // i.e. starts at 135deg ends at 45deg with large arc flag
    // REMEMBER!! angle=0 starts on X axis and then increases clockwise
    function getDialCoords(radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
      var cx = GaugeDefaults.centerX,
          cy = GaugeDefaults.centerY;
      return {
        end: getCartesian(cx, cy, radius, endAngle),
       start: getCartesian(cx, cy, radius, startAngle)
      };
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Gauge object. This should be called without the 'new' operator. Various options
     * can be passed for the gauge:
     * {
     *    dialStartAngle: The angle to start the dial. MUST be greater than dialEndAngle. Default 135deg
     *    dialEndAngle: The angle to end the dial. Default 45deg
     *    dialRadius: The gauge's radius. Default 400
     *    max: The maximum value of the gauge. Default 100
     *    value: The starting value of the gauge. Default 0
     *    label: The function on how to render the center label (Should return a value)
     * }
     * @param {Element} elem The DOM into which to render the gauge
     * @param {Object} opts The gauge options
     * @return a Gauge object
     */
    return function Gauge(elem, opts) {
      opts = shallowCopy({}, defaultOptions, opts);
      var gaugeContainer = elem,
          limit = opts.max,
          min = opts.min,
          value = normalize(opts.value, min, limit),
          radius = opts.dialRadius,
          displayValue = opts.showValue,
          startAngle = opts.dialStartAngle,
          endAngle = opts.dialEndAngle,
          valueDialClass = opts.valueDialClass,
          valueTextClass = opts.valueClass,
          valueLabelClass = opts.valueLabelClass,
          dialClass = opts.dialClass,
          gaugeClass = opts.gaugeClass,
          gaugeColor = opts.color,
          gaugeValueElem,
          gaugeValuePath,
          label = opts.label,
          viewBox = opts.viewBox,
          instance;

      if(startAngle < endAngle) {
        console.log("WARN! startAngle < endAngle, Swapping");
        var tmp = startAngle;
        startAngle = endAngle;
        endAngle = tmp;
      }

      function pathString(radius, startAngle, endAngle, largeArc) {
        var coords = getDialCoords(radius, startAngle, endAngle),
            start = coords.start,
            end = coords.end,
            largeArcFlag = typeof(largeArc) === "undefined" ? 1 : largeArc;

        return [
          "M", start.x, start.y,
          "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 1, end.x, end.y
        ].join(" ");
      }

      function initializeGauge(elem) {
        gaugeValueElem = svg("text", {
          x: 50,
          y: 50,
          fill: "#999",
          "class": valueTextClass,
          "font-size": "100%",
          "font-family": "sans-serif",
          "font-weight": "normal",
          "text-anchor": "middle",
          "alignment-baseline": "middle",
          "dominant-baseline": "central"
        });

        gaugeValuePath = svg("path", {
          "class": valueDialClass,
          fill: "none",
          stroke: "#666",
          "stroke-width": 2.5,
          d: pathString(radius, startAngle, startAngle) // value of 0
        });

        var angle = getAngle(100, 360 - Math.abs(startAngle - endAngle));
        var flag = angle <= 180 ? 0 : 1;
        var gaugeElement = svg("svg", {"viewBox": viewBox || "0 0 100 100", "class": gaugeClass}, [
          svg("path", {
            "class": dialClass,
            fill: "none",
            stroke: "#eee",
            "stroke-width": 2,
            d: pathString(radius, startAngle, endAngle, flag)
          }),
          svg("g", { "class": "text-container" }, [gaugeValueElem]),
          gaugeValuePath
        ]);
        elem.appendChild(gaugeElement);
      }

      function updateGauge(theValue, frame) {
        var val = getValueInPercentage(theValue, 0, 100),
            // angle = getAngle(val, 360 - Math.abs(endAngle - startAngle)),
            angle = getAngle(val, 360 - Math.abs(startAngle - endAngle)),
            // this is because we are using arc greater than 180deg
            flag = angle <= 180 ? 0 : 1;
        if(displayValue) {
          gaugeValueElem.textContent = label.call(opts, theValue);
        }
        gaugeValuePath.setAttribute("d", pathString(radius, startAngle, angle + startAngle, flag));
      }

      function setGaugeColor(value, duration) {
        var c = gaugeColor.call(opts, value),
            dur = duration * 1000,
            pathTransition = "stroke " + dur + "ms ease";
            // textTransition = "fill " + dur + "ms ease";

        gaugeValuePath.style.stroke = c;
        gaugeValuePath.style["-webkit-transition"] = pathTransition;
        gaugeValuePath.style["-moz-transition"] = pathTransition;
        gaugeValuePath.style.transition = pathTransition;
        /*
        gaugeValueElem.style = [
          "fill: " + c,
          "-webkit-transition: " + textTransition,
          "-moz-transition: " + textTransition,
          "transition: " + textTransition,
        ].join(";");
        */
      }

      instance = {
        setMaxValue: function(max) {
          limit = max;
          updateGauge(value);
        },
        setValue: function(val) {
          value = normalize(val, 0, 100);
          if(gaugeColor) {
            setGaugeColor(value, 0)
          }
          updateGauge(value);
        },
        setValueAnimated: function(val, duration) {
           var oldVal = value;
          value = val;


          if(gaugeColor) {
            setGaugeColor(value, duration);
          }
          Animation({
            start: 50,
            end: value,
            duration: duration || 1,
            step: function(val, frame) {
              updateGauge(val, frame);
            }
          });
        },
        getValue: function() {
          return value;
        }
      };

      initializeGauge(gaugeContainer);
      instance.setValue(value);
      return instance;
    };
  })();

  return Gauge;
});

  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <div class="display">
                    <div id="gauge2" class="gauge-container two" style="display:inline-block; min-height:100px;min-width:100px;float: left;width: 100%; height: 100%;padding-left: 300px;overflow: hidden"></div>
         </div>

      <script>
         var pad = function(tar) {}


         var gauge2 = Gauge(
           document.getElementById("gauge2"),
         {
             min: -100,
             max: 100,
             dialStartAngle: 180,
             dialEndAngle: 0,
             value: 50,
             viewBox: "0 0 100 57",
             color: function(value) {
               if(value > 80) {
                 return "#5ee432";
               }else if(value > 60) {
                 return "#fffa50";
               }else if(value < 40) {
                 return "#f7aa38";
               }else {
                 return "#ef4655";
               }
             }
           }
         );


         (function loop() {

           gauge2.setValueAnimated(100, 3);
         })();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The page is in:
http://booksandreviews.ml/?p=29

What to change in the code so in the wordpress site the size will also change?

I tried changing the style everywhere.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NehaSoni I trimmed it. It is complex object animation so all the code is needed. The html combined of just one div element. If you copy it to html file it will load big, but in wordpress it is not.